SSAS Tabular - How to avoid the initial delay of the first query in Analysis Services?
I have a database in Analysis Services Tabular and a table with direct query.
When I'm creating a table (without relationships and nothing stranger) and after I do a simple query against that table then it take a loooong time
For example, after creating the table I simply query it with "evaluate" and it takes many seconds.
How can I avoid that initial delay?
In the followings executions of my query it takes only 1 second
EVALUATE MyTable

I've try processing my table.
It seems that Analysis Services does not know the metadata of the table and needs to build it beforehand (like a full processing)
Even though it has already created the table few seconds ago
If I do the comparison with SQL Server, there I create the table, then query it and it doesn't take long.

DirectQuery means the data doesn't exist in SSAS. It's all in the source database and your performance is largely tied to that database, not SSAS. If it's DirectQuery, you are probably waiting for data to be cached in the source database. Once the data is cached, it will be faster. Most time in DirectQuery is database time and has nothing to do with SSAS.

but I'm not using PowerBI . I'm talking only  about Analysis Services .
A table in Analasis Services connect to a sql table

Note that I'm querying the data in Management Studio using a simple EVALUATE

Sorry, forgot where I was! I updated the answer for SSAS, not Power BI. Performance comments are the same. Your performance is still tied to the source database, not SSAS. Tracing is more involved for SSAS, and I can't point you to the exact documentation, but search on SQL Profiler if you want to prove this with a trace. I think Chris Webb had some good documentation on his website. You could try Import mode instead of DirectQuery and you should see a longer Process time and faster EVALUATE time.
